# emq and Spring AMQP

Tags: spring, mqtt, spring-amqp, emq

I am new to both Spring AMQP and MQTT world. I have a legacy application which uses Rabbitmq as broker for mqtt messages.There are plans to use emqtt as broker and I want to know if my existing listeners ( on mqtt topics) written using Spring AMQP can work with emqtt or not ? I am just trying to save the effort of rewriting all those listeners using MqttClient.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may consider to use Spring Integration MQTT Channel Adapters instead: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/mqtt.html

Comment: @ArtemBilan Thanks. But will it work with existing routing keys. In my case the routing keys are pattern based. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @ArtemBilan Got it.. IMqttClient  allows wildcards in topic names for the subscription.